# How to "stash" random state generator state

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I'm seeding a random number generator for reproducible results with:

```
import random

SEED = 32412542
random.seed(SEED)
```

I'd like to make it return "non-reproducible" random values for only one part of a program, as in:

```
import random

SEED = 32412542
random.seed(SEED)

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

res = random.sample(my_list, len(my_list))  # I would like result of this to be the same between runs of the program.

# Do some reproducible calculations, such as training neural network.
print(res)  # E.g. prints [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]

# What to do here?
res = random.sample(my_list, len(my_list))  # I would like result of this to be different between runs.

# Do some non-reproducible calculations, such as picking neural network parameters randomly.
print(res)  # Prints some random order.

res = random.sample(my_list, len(my_list))  # I would like result of this to be the same between runs of the program.

# Do some reproducible calculations, such as training neural network.
print(res)  # E.g. prints [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

What I came up with so far is to seed with no parameter right before I'd like it to become non-reproducible and then re-seed with the `SEED` value afterwards:

```
import random

SEED = 32412542
random.seed(SEED)

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

res = random.sample(my_list, len(my_list))
print(res)  # Prints: [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]

random.seed()
res = random.sample(my_list, len(my_list))
print(res)  # Prints some random order.

random.seed(SEED)
res = random.sample(my_list, len(my_list))
print(res)  # Prints: [3, 2, 4, 1, 5], so exactly what has been printed before.
```

The problem is that after re-seeding, exactly the same set of random values is produced (obviously - in the end that's the purpose of seeding with a specific value), which I don't want to happen. I'd like to somehow restore the previous state of the random generator. Is that possible?

Comment: If you create an instance of `random.Random` you should be able to `.getstate()` and `.setstate()`

Comment: Or you use two "Random" objects of which one is initialized with a seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this using the `random` functions but you can by creating an instance of the `Random` class. [As the documentation states:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

> Class `Random` can also be subclassed if you want to use a different
>   basic generator of your own devising: in that case, override the
>   `random()`, `seed()`, **`getstate()`, and `setstate()` methods**. Optionally, a
>   new generator can supply a getrandbits() method — this allows
>   randrange() to produce selections over an arbitrarily large range.

Example:

```
>>> import random
>>> r = random.Random()
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
545
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
349
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
745
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
792
>>> state = r.getstate()
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
52
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
799
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
586
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
581
>>> r.setstate(state)
>>> r.randint(1,1000)
52
>>> r.randint(1,1000)
799
>>> r.randint(1,1000)
586
>>> r.randint(1,1000)
581
```

---

Actually [you can even using the functions from the `random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getstate), my bad:

> `random.getstate()` Return an object capturing the current internal
>   state of the generator. This object can be passed to `setstate()` to
>   restore the state.
>
> `random.setstate(state)` state should have been obtained from a previous
>   call to `getstate()`, and `setstate()` restores the internal state of the
>   generator to what it was at the time `getstate()` was called.

Comment: The second part was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `random` (unlike an instance of `random.Random` or a subclass of `random.Random`) is global state, and I discourage it for the same reasons that [`numpy.random.*` was discouraged](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst); its use should be limited to unit tests.